# ArrayList shows in red and won't compile --- java android

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

The

> mytextview.setText(xyzList[0][0]);

line fails (RED).
I am mixing up everything, I am afraid.
I know it is something simple.
I am trying to write the first instance of the array I filled with the dan_akdag.pgn textfile (with a " " split) on the related TextView.

Can anyone help me?
I'm still a novice.

```
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AssetManager manager;
        String line = null;
        List<String[]> xyzList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        String[][] xyz;
        InputStream is = null;
        InputStreamReader isr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
            try {
            manager = getAssets();
            is = manager.open("dan_akdag.pgn");
            isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                xyzList.add(line.split(" "));
            }
            xyz = (String[][]) xyzList.toArray();
            TextView mytextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showarray);
         **   mytextview.setText(xyzList[0][0]);   **

          } catch (IOException e1) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Problem!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } finally {

            try {
                //if(reader != null)
              //  reader.close();
                if (br != null)
                br.close();
                if (isr != null)
                isr.close();
                if (is != null)
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            // dosomething
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }


         }


     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
mytextview.setText(xyzList[0][0]);
```

to

```
mytextview.setText(xyz[0][0]);
```

since `xyzList` is not an array while `xyz` is.

Also change

```
xyz = (String[][]) xyzList.toArray();
```

to

```
xyz = xyzList.toArray(new String[xyzList.size()][]);
```

Casting an `Object[]` to a `String[][]` will not work. It will throw a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: I did as you said. It gives the following rebuild error:Error:Content is not allowed in prolog.
D:\Android_Dosyalar\Proje\TextToArray\app\src\main\res\assets\akdag_ljubicic.pgn
Error:(1, 1) Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> D:\Android_Dosyalar\Proje\TextToArray\app\src\main\res\assets\akdag_ljubicic.pgn:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: The folder structure:res
assets
akdag_ljubicic.pgn
akdag_serradimigni.pgn
dan_akdag.pgn

Comment: The file is  a text file and it contains the elements of a chess game. By the way the R is giving RED also right now. :)

Comment: It was the location of the assets folder the correct place should be         <project>/src/main/assets. Thank you again ...Regards, Aziz

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
mytextview.setText(xyzList[0][0]);
```

to

```
mytextview.setText(xyz[0][0]);
```

**xyzList** refers to your `ArrayList`, not to an `array`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Regards